# Обратный отсчёт в Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Нужно сделать обратный отсчёт на геометрической фигуре. Получилось сделать обратный отсчёт в названии программы (title). Как это перенести на холст и на сам круг?

```py
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
t = 60
def countdown():
    global t, root
    root.title(str(t))
    if t==0: root.destroy()
    t-=1
    root.after(1000, countdown)
countdown()
root.mainloop()
```

[image: описание]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root)
...
 canvas.delete("all")
canvas.create_text(20, 20, text=str(t), fill="black", font=('Courier 10 normal'))
canvas.pack()
```